# Blender - A Python script for selecting the left-half of a mesh from front-view, except the vertices along the center

Tags: python, scripting, 3d, blender

There is a sequence of actions I perform multiple times per-project when making things in Blender. It's not the biggest time save in the world, but I thought it would be cool to automate this because I do it so often.

[image: Selecting the left-half from front-view, except the vertices along the center]

[A quick YouTube video of the specific process I'm talking about.](https://youtu.be/WbzKqgUOSBU)

Most of the scripting for this seems pretty straight-forward. I managed to get most of it done, up until I have to select the vertices. As far as I understand, it will take some mathy stuff to pull this off, and I struggle to understand how to achieve such a thing. [**This thread**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128368/get-the-exact-half-of-a-mesh-with-bpy) was very relevant, and it seems like the right path, but it selects the center vertices, and I can't comprehend the code well enough to modify this properly... If there's an easy edit to this code, or a better method for selecting the vertices like this, I would really appreciate some direction.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I did in-fact carefully read through the code in the thread I linked, and solved the problem on my own by editing the value at the end :D

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils.geometry import distance_point_to_plane
from mathutils import Vector

context = bpy.context

def bbox(ob):
    return (Vector(b) for b in ob.bound_box)

def bbox_center(ob):
    return sum(bbox(ob), Vector()) / 8

def bbox_axes(ob):
    bb = list(bbox(ob))
    return tuple(bb[i] - bb[0] for i in (4, 3, 1))

ob = context.edit_object
o = bbox_center(ob)
x, y, z = bbox_axes(ob) 

print(o, x, y, z)
# select left right

me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
for v in bm.verts:
    v.select = distance_point_to_plane(v.co, o, x) >= 0.1 # Simply changed this from 0 to 0.1!

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```